# Nested generic interface, but don't mix concrete implementations in the nesting

Tags: c#, generics, nested, polymorphism

I have this generic interface with the following implementations:

```
public interface IInterface<T, U> where U : IInterface<T, U> {}
public class ConcreteA<T> : IInterface<T, ConcreteA<T>> {}
public class ConcreteB<T> : IInterface<T, ConcreteB<T>> {}
```

I also wrote the following method to flatten nested interfaces. The idea is that if I have a `ConcreteA<ConcreteA<T>>` object, that's redundant, and I can just apply some logic to obtain a simple `ConcreteA<T>`.

```
public static S Flatten<R, S, T>(this R nested)
    where R : IInterface<S, R>
    where S : IInterface<T, S> { 
    // logic to flatten the input
}
```

The problem is that I only want to flatten things if both layers of the nested input are the same concrete implementation of the interface, e.g., `ConcreteA<ConcreteA<T>>` but not `ConcreteB<ConcreteA<T>>`; the flattening code will give a wrong result if you mix concrete implementations. The compiler will not enforce this for my method, so I would need to check it at runtime using reflection for generics, which I would rather avoid.

What should I do so that calling `Flatten()` on `ConcreteA<ConcreteA<T>>` compiles but calling on `ConcreteB<ConcreteA<T>>` fails to compile?

Comment: A nice puzzle. Some initial (failed) tests in solving it make me suspect that this would require [higher kinded generics](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/339), which C# currently does not support (so that you could write `public static C<T> Flatten<C, T>(this C<C<T>> nested) where ...`).